# Change the directory for default module

Tags: php, zend-framework

How can I change the directory for the default module. I am using Zend Framework modular directory structure:

```
modules
    default
        controllers
            IndexController.php
        etc
    other-module
```

But how can I change the directory for the default module? I would like it to be called Api. So I would have:

```
modules
    Api
        controllers
            IndexController.php
    other-module
```

I want the URIs to stay the same so:

```
http://localhost
```

Will route to modules/Api/controllers/IndexController.php and run the indexAction.

This is what I have in the bootstrap

```
protected function _initFrontController()
{
    $front = Zend_Controller_Front::getInstance();
    $front->addModuleDirectory(APPLICATION_PATH.'/modules');
    return $front;
}
```

Comment: I am not sure but try like this in your apllication.ini `resources.frontController.moduleDirectory = APPLICATION_PATH "/modules/api"`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In `application/config.ini`:

```
# where to find modules
resources.frontController.moduleDirectory = APPLICATION_PATH "/modules"

# set the default module
resources.frontController.defaultModule = "api"

# which modules to activate
resources.modules.api   = "api"
resources.moduler.other = "other"
```

Then you can remove the `_initFrontController()` method from your `Bootstrap`.

Note the character case here. Typically module names (as referenced in the config file and in routes) are lower-case. Also, the file name of the module will be lower-case (Ex: `application/modules/api`). Module-specific class names (say, a controller within an admin module) will capitalize the first char of the module name as the class prefix (Ex: `class Admin_ArticleController extends Zend_Controller_Action`).

[For hyphenated and camelCase module names - like your 'other-module' example - I forget precisely how module-specific classes should be prefixed, but it's easy enough to chase down if you really need it.]

Answer (score 1):

In your config.ini

```
resources.frontController.moduleDirectory = APPLICATION_PATH "/modules"
resources.modules[] = "default"
resources.modules[] = "api"
```

Your folder structure is ok